# CLLocationManager issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm learning about user localization in swift. I'm trying to print localization on console (later I will use it for info on label, so I want to check if it works), but I have no idea why it prints nothing. Even if delete conversions to string, and leave just for printing anything, it still doesn't work. Please help.

Yes, I added `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and 
`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var myPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {

        print("Got location: \(newLocation.coordinate.latitude), \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

        myPosition = newLocation.coordinate

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you double check the "location settings" in the settings app for your app? Maybe when you ran it the first time, you accidentally turned location settings for this app. Check the `authorizationStatus`, to see what it returns. Also, make sure you test this on physical device, as simulator behaves differently from physical devices.

Comment: did not help...

Comment: As an aside, the term "localization" generally refers to the internationalization (language, number/date formatters, etc.). You're asking about "location services", not "localization".

Comment: Have you added the two fields in info.plist?

Comment: Yes, I added both.

Comment: Are you running on the simulator or a physical device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didUpdateToLocation` is an outdated method of the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. It is available in 10.6 and earlier. Instead, use `didUpdateLocations`, which will return an array of all location objects in order of time recent. You then access the latest, newest location be grabbing the last object in the returned array.

So try this

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

          var latestLocation: CLLocation = locations.last;
         print("Got location: \(latestLocation.coordinate.latitude), \(latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

    }
```

tell me how it goes.

Comment: Still nothing. It seems like this func never gets called. No idea why.
No other errors, doesn't crash.

Comment: get a break point on the first line in the function, see if it gets called

Comment: also, for now, get rid of stopUpdatingLocation - and make sure you do follow my answer either way as it will be a step forward! How did you add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to plist file?

Comment: Have made a few changes to my answer, try it again

Comment: still nothing... This function is not called

Comment: does the location service icon appear in iPhone menu?

Comment: well the problem probably isn't the code then...are you sure the plist file and your settings are setup correctly? have you ever had the alert box asking permission?

Comment: for the first time it appeared.

Comment: and if you go to settings> your app>lcation> it is not on never? and has an AppExplanation of the plist string?

Comment: hey I found something like "Simulate locations". The problem is I cannot set it permanently. I have to check it every single time, when I run an app, and it turn off immediately.

Comment: Simulating location is no use for now - especially as you want updating long/lat data.

Comment: So how can I enable it to show location every time automatically?

Comment: settings> your app>lcation>

Comment: okay, I think I found the solution. Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme and set location. Thanks for help. And of courde I used your code.